# Windows Key + X shortcut stopped working in Windows 8 64-bit laptop?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

Okay so I got a new laptop, it's a week old, it is an Asus X501A-XX277H that came with windows 8 installed. At first the shortcut <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+ <kbd>X</kbd> worked but now it does not while all the other shortcuts work. When I press it the pointer loads for a split second but nothing happens. I also cannot access the advanced context menu by putting the pointer in the left corner and right-clicking?

I had to download a different touchpad drive as the windows 8 scrolling and swiping gestures always stopped working once my laptop came out of sleep/ hibernation. Downloading the Elantech driver resolved that problem, could it be the cause of this one though?

Any help will be very much appreciated as it is driving me mad!

Comment: Uninstall any software of you installed that interacts and/or changes shortcuts on your system.